# Visual Studio jump to next error shortcut?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, ide

When a compile fails in VB.NET in Visual Studio 2008, an Error List pops up at the bottom of the screen. To jump to an error, I double click on an error in the error list.

Is there a shortcut to automatically jump to the next error in the list? It gets a little bit tedious at times having to reach down and double click a list that I like to keep collapsed.

Answer (score 565, accepted):

<kbd>F8</kbd> (and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to go backwards).

Or at least that's what it is in my keyboard profile - you can go to tools\options\environment\keyboard and check out Edit.GoToNextLocation.

**Note** If you configured Visual Studio using VB keyboard settings, no key has been assigned to this function. You need to pick your own and assign them.

Comment: If you configured Visual Studio using VB keyboard settings, no key has been assigned to this function. You need to pick your own and assign them.

Comment: Works with C++ projects, too.

Comment: If luckily you don't have errors F8 goes to next warning.

Comment: so messed up. was happy to find that it was assigned to F4 in my config. but F4 is set to swit chthe current display on my laptop. so much to deal with... thanks though. solution (CTRL+SHIFT+F12) below worked.

Comment: Important: at least for VS 2017, I needed to in my "error view" have selected both "Build + Intellisense" in order for these shortcuts to work.

Comment: You can restrict this to errors in the current document or project using the drop-down in the Error List (defaults to whole solution).

Comment: Just in case if it wasnt clear, `F8` jumps to next item (be it errors, search results, symbol reference search etc). It depends on which pane had your focus last.

Answer (score 204):

Funny because I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> which is **View.NextError**.

I wonder what's the difference between *View.NextError* and *Edit.GoToNextLocation*.

Comment: Edit.GoToNextLocation works also when you navigate through search in files results

Comment: When dealing with multiple projects I find `View.NextError` much more useful. This way I don't navigate to errors in other projects.

Comment: One diff between View.NextError and Edit.GoToNextLocation is that View.NextError is specific to the error list, but Edit.GoToNextLocation is applicable to error list, search results, find all refs etc

Comment: definitely more useful. and beside F8 above is just decreasing my screen brightness.

Comment: @victorn.you might have `Fn` keys active. Try to press `Fn`+`F8`

Comment: Works in VS2019.

Comment: Warning: On ubuntu this toggles composite mode which turns your screen black. Press ctrl-alt-f1 to get your screen back.

Answer (score 22):

If you have ReSharper installed, you can use `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextErrorInSolution`, the default mapping for which is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>. This is the equivalent of clicking on the error icon shown in the bottom right of Visual Studio's status bar:

[image: ReSharper solution errors screenshot]

Comment: Useful; thanks. Seems that `Alt`+`PgDn` does the same thing, but for Warnings.

Comment: Better than the default VS shortcut which seem to also always include warnings, so here you can pick if you want to include warnings or not which is nice.

Comment: Additionally, without `ReSharper` in my instance of Visual Studio using Visual Basic 6 mapping, it appears the same keyboard shortcut was also in place by default.

Answer (score 3):

### For Visual Studio CODE (2022)

1. Open **Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts**
   [image]
2. Find **go to problem in files**
   [image]
3. Set the shortcut keys with your taste. (Default value is `F8`, `Shift`+`F8`.)